# Case Reopen changes owner to System

Tags: case, email2case

When a user closes a case a workflow rule sets the owner to the user who closes the case.

We have a workflow rule that allows an email message to Reopen a case when a reply is received.  This currently includes a field update that sets the new owner to a queue and a field update to change the status back to "New".

I want to remove this field update from the Workflow rule so the case owner stays the same as the user who closed it when the case is reopened.

Unfortunately if I remove the field update the case owner is changed to "System".

On checking the support process I can see this user is used for automation tasks (email-to-case, case assignment, live chat etc).  We do have an Assignment Rule (no escalation or entitlements) and I know this kicks in as the status is being changed back to "New" but the assignment rule should detect this and change the owner back to the queue as well.  I know this isn't happening, which is fine, I don't want it too.  I am just at a loss as to why the "System" user is appearing as the owner at all, I don't want the owner changed when the case is opened.

We have 1 triggers but it only adds a contact if it can find one in the object.

Edit: I tried adding a new top priority rule into the Case Assignment Rule, this simply detects the reopen by an email reply with (ISCHANGED(Status) && Email_In__c = True) but whilst it did change the owner (do not change owner was ticked).  This seemed to work but then another piece of automation is clearly changing the user:

The case history shows it happening at the same time as the status change.

Case Assignment Rules:
[image]

Comment: If you change your automation user for support process, does the owner change to whoever you selected?

Comment: Yes it does actually.  I know that it says that this user is chosen for case changes from Assignment Rules (we have), Escalation Rules (we don't have), On-Demand Emal to case (we have) and self service portal (we don't have).  I have checked every setting I have found in email to case and don't think its that.  I have checked my assignment rule too and don't think it's that (just added screenshot)

Comment: Note the assignment rule does assign if the owner is System, that isn't involved here, that is actually to try and detect Live Chat's that also get created (currently the offline forms are submitted as System too)

Comment: How does this workflow rule that reopens the case work?

Comment: thanks @KrisGoncalves  It runs on email object, when an email is incoming and the case is closed and the case type is not of type "spam". Executed anytime to match that criteria and has the two field updates (status back to New and owner back to the queue).

Comment: if you go into your `email-to-case` in setup and look at some of the routing addresses, is the `Case Owner` the System user?

Comment: there is nobody - they are blank

Comment: Not sure if you're in a test environment, but if you change that to some random user - is that the user who gets assigned the case when the email comes in to reopen it?

Comment: I changed it to myself, new cases were assigned to me but on re-opening it was assigned to system again :(

Comment: It might be beneficial to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103578/discussion-on-question-by-sfdcbeginner) when we have time as opposed to cluttering the comments. I might not respond immediately, but I'll try to check.

Comment: I would appreciate it (the link didn't work)

Comment: Ah, sorry it must have closed due to inactivity. [This one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103937/discussion-with-sfdc-beginner) should work and feel free to leave comments there even if I'm not on as I'll see them later.